# Simple MySQL query with performance issues

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following simple MySQL query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE mainID
FROM tableName 
WHERE otherID3=19
AND dateStartCol >= '2012-08-01' 
AND dateStartCol <= '2012-08-31';
```

When I run this it takes 0.29 seconds to bring back 36074 results. When I increase my date period to bring back more results (65703) it runs in 0.56. When I run other similar SQL queries on the same server but on different tables (some tables are larger) the results come back in approximately 0.01 seconds.

Although 0.29 isn't slow - this is a basic part for a complex query and this timing means that it is not scalable.

See below for the table definition and indexes.

I know it's not server load as I have the same issue on a development server which has very little usage.

```
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| mainID                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| otherID1                  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| otherID2                  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| otherID3                  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| keyword                   | varchar(200) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dateStartCol              | date         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| timeStartCol              | time         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dateEndCol                | date         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| timeEndCol                | time         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| statusCode                | int(1)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| uRL                       | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hostname                  | varchar(200) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| IPAddress                 | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cookieVal                 | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| keywordVal                | varchar(60)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dateTimeCol               | datetime     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


+--------------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table              | Non_unique | Key_name                      | Seq_in_index | Column_name               | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| tableName          |          0 | PRIMARY                       |            1 | mainID                    | A         |      661990 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tableName          |          1 | idx_otherID1                  |            1 | otherID1                   | A         |      330995 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tableName          |          1 | idx_otherID2                  |            1 | otherID2                   | A         |          25 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tableName          |          1 | idx_otherID3                  |            1 | otherID3                   | A         |          48 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tableName          |          1 | idx_dateStartCol              |            1 | dateStartCol               | A         |         187 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tableName          |          1 | idx_timeStartCol              |            1 | timeStartCol               | A         |       73554 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
|tableName          |          1 | idx_dateEndCol                 |            1 | dateEndCol                 | A         |         188 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
|tableName          |          1 | idx_timeEndCol                 |            1 | timeEndCol                 | A         |       73554 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tableName          |          1 | idx_keyword                   |            1 | keyword                    | A         |       82748 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tableName           |          1 | idx_hostname                 |            1 | hostname                   | A         |        2955 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| tableName           |          1 | idx_dateTimeCol              |            1 | dateTimeCol                | A         |      220663 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tableName           |          1 | idx_statusCode               |            1 | statusCode                 | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+--------------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Explain Output:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+----------------------------------+-------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys                    | key               | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+----------------------------------+-------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tableName | range | idx_otherID3,idx_dateStartCol | idx_dateStartCol | 3       | NULL | 66875 |    75.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+----------------------------------+-------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried `AND dateStartCol BETWEEN '2012-08-01' 
AND '2012-08-31'`. Not sure if it'll help, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I have tried the BETWEEN and there is no significant difference in the times (goes from 0.29 to 0.28). -Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is really your query (and not a simplified version of same), then this ought to achieve best results:

```
 CREATE INDEX table_ndx on tableName( otherID3, dateStartCol, mainID);
```

The first index entry means that the first match in the `WHERE` is very fast; the same also applies with `dateStartCol`. The third field is very small and does not slow the index appreciably, but allows for the datum you require to be found immediately in the index with no table access at all.

It is important that the keys are in the *same* index. In the `EXPLAIN` you posted, each key is in an index of its own, so even if MySQL chooses the best index, the performances will not be optimal. I'd try and use less indexes, for they also have a cost (shameless plug: [Can Indices actually decrease SELECT performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361510/can-indices-actually-decrease-select-performance/11361670#11361670) ).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a recurrent or important query then create a multiple column index:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON tableName (otherID3, dateStartCol)
```

Delete the non used indexes as they make table changes more expensive.

BTW you don't need two separate columns for date and time. You can combine then in a `datetime` or `timestamp` type. One less column and one less index.

The `explain` output shows it chose the `dateStartCol` index so you could try the opposite I suggested above:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON tableName (dateStartCol, otherID3)
```

Notice that the query's dateStartCol condition will still get 75% of the rows so not much improvement, if any, in using that single index.

How unique is `otherID3`? If there are not many repeated `otherID3` you can [hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html) the engine to use it.

Comment: I have tried doing this but it takes the query time from 0.29 to 0.25.  Also all indexes are used - not necessarily in this SQL but in other reports therefore they cannot be deleted.

Comment: @mh1 Edit based on the `explain`

Comment: Indeed, that should do it. However, I am pretty sure the order of the fields in that index should not matter, because in an AND query MySQL can decide to reorder them anyway. If that makes a difference, it could even be a bug.

Comment: @DanielSchneller I'm pretty sure the order matters. Edited with `hint`

Comment: Thinking about it again, you might be right. If one of the fields has a much better cardinality (i. e. more different values, therefore being better to eliminate candidates) than the other one, MySQL might decide to ignore the combined index if that more specific column was not the 1st one in the index and choose a different index altogether.

Answer (score 0):

First try to add the right key. It seems like dateStartCol is more selective than otherID3

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD KEY idx_dates(dateStartCol, dateStartCol)
```

Second - please make sure you select only rows you need by adding LIMIT clause to the SELECT. This will should up the query. Try like this:

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE mainID
FROM tableName 
WHERE otherID3=19
AND dateStartCol >= '2012-08-01' 
AND dateStartCol <= '2012-08-31'
LIMIT 10;

Please also make sure that your MySQL tuned up properly. You may want to check key_buffer_size and innodb_buffer_pool_size as described in http://astellar.com/2011/12/why-is-stock-mysql-slow/

Comment: LIMIT will not make much of a difference, because it will do the same query first and then only return a part of the results. As this is only a query for a few IDs, transmission of the data will not be the expensive part.

Comment: Your are right about data transmission, but in some cases MySQL will stop reading data when limit is reached. It seems like IO involved heavily in this case it might help. But anyway 300ms is way too long for this type of query irregardless of LIMIT