# Querying minimum value in SQL Server is a lot longer than querying all the rows

Tags: sql-server, performance, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2012, database-partitioning

I'm currently confronted with a strange behaviour in my database when I'm querying a minimum ID for a specific date in a table contains about a hundred million rows. The query is quite simple :

```
SELECT MIN(Id) FROM Connection WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE DateConnection = '2012-06-26'
```

This query nevers end, at least I let it run for hours. The DateConnection column is not an index neither included in one. So I would understand that this query can last quite a bit. But I tried the following query which runs in few seconds :

```
SELECT Id FROM Connection WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE DateConnection = '2012-06-26'
```

It returns 300k rows.

My table is defined as this :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Connection](  
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [DateConnection] [datetime] NOT NULL,  
    [TimeConnection] [time](7) NOT NULL,  
    [Hour]  AS (datepart(hour,[TimeConnection])) PERSISTED NOT NULL,  
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Connection] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   
    (  
        [Hour] ASC,  
        [Id] ASC  
    )  
)
```

And it has the following index :

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Connection_Id] ON [dbo].[Connection]  
(  
    [Id] ASC  
)ON [PRIMARY]
```

One solutions I find using this strange behaviour is using the following code. But it seems to me quite a bit heavy for such a simple query.

```
create table #TempId
(
    [Id] bigint
)
go

insert into #TempId
select id from partitionned_connection with(nolock) where dateconnection = '2012-06-26'

declare @displayId bigint
select @displayId = min(Id) from #CoIdTest

print @displayId 
go

drop table #TempId
go
```

Has anybody been confronted to this behaviour and what is the cause of it ? Is the minimum aggregate scanning the entire table ? And if this is the case why the simple select does not ?

Comment: Have you run the query with the Show Execution Plan option on? I suspect you are seeing the difference between an Index Seek and an Index Scan/Table Scan. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx for the Execution Plan options. You could also test by adding an index to the dateconnection column - this should make locating all of the rows for your given date faster, but the execution plan will suggest indexes for you.

Comment: @dash : I didn't even tried it because this query didn't end. I just launched it again and this time it took 25 minutes and I manage to get the execution plan.  It is doing an Index Scan which outputs Id and Hour, but this operation takes 0%. Then it inner joins the result with a key lookup. This is this lookup which takes 99% of the time.  In this step the Predicate is `DateConnection = '2012-06-26 00:00:00.000'`. The seek predicate is : `Seek Keys[1]: Prefix: PtnId1000; Hour; Id = Scalar Operator([PtnId1000]); Scalar Operator([Hour]); Scalar Operator([Id])`

Comment: The execution plan does not advise me to add any index, and I wanted toi avoid doing so because it might represent a significative increase in memory usage.

Comment: Your temp table looks like a good solution. Consider adding a PK in your temp table. Test it both ways to see if it helps.

Comment: @RobGarrison, in what way would a CTE help?

Comment: [Basically the same issue as here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481818/sql-why-is-select-count-mincol-maxcol-faster-then-select-mincol-max/7482342#7482342)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is the non-aligned nonclustered index, combined with the statistical limitation Martin Smith [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645223/querying-minimum-value-in-sql-server-is-a-lot-longer-than-querying-all-the-rows/11677589#comment15488029_11645223) (see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481818/sql-why-is-select-count-mincol-maxcol-faster-then-select-mincol-max/7482342#7482342) to another question for details).

Your table is partitioned on `[Hour]` along these lines:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF (integer)
AS RANGE RIGHT
FOR VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23);

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS
AS PARTITION PF ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);

-- Partitioned
CREATE TABLE dbo.Connection
(
    Id              bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    DateConnection  datetime NOT NULL,
    TimeConnection  time(7) NOT NULL,
    [Hour]  AS (DATEPART(HOUR, TimeConnection)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Connection]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (  
        [Hour] ASC,  
        [Id] ASC  
    )
    ON PS ([Hour])
);

-- Not partitioned
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Connection_Id]
ON dbo.Connection
(  
    Id ASC
)ON [PRIMARY];

-- Pretend there are lots of rows
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Connection WITH ROWCOUNT = 200000000, PAGECOUNT = 4000000;
```

The query and execution plan are:

```
SELECT 
    MinID = MIN(c.Id)
FROM dbo.Connection AS c WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) 
WHERE
    c.DateConnection = '2012-06-26';
```

[image: Selected plan]

The optimizer takes advantage of the index (ordered on `Id`) to transform the `MIN` aggregate to a `TOP (1)` - since the minimum value will by definition be the first value encountered in the ordered stream. (If the nonclustered index were also partitioned, the optimizer would not choose this strategy since the required ordering would be lost).

The slight complication is that we also need to apply the predicate in the `WHERE` clause, which requires a lookup to the base table to fetch the `DateConnection` value. The statistical limitation Martin mentions explains why the optimizer estimates it will only need to check 119 rows from the ordered index before finding one with a `DateConnection` value that will match the `WHERE clause`. The hidden correlation between `DateConnection` and `Id` values means this estimate is a very long way off.

*In case you are interested*, the Compute Scalar calculates which partition to perform the Key Lookup into. For each row from the nonclustered index, it computes an expression like `[PtnId1000] = Scalar Operator(RangePartitionNew([dbo].[Connection].[Hour] as [c].[Hour],(1),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23)))`, and this is used as the leading key of the lookup seek. There is prefetching (read-ahead) on the nested loops join, but this needs to be an ordered prefetch to preserve the sorting required by the `TOP (1)` optimization.

### Solution

We can avoid the statistical limitation (without using query hints) by finding the minimum `Id` for each `Hour` value, and then taking the minimum of the per-hour minimums:

```
-- Global minimum
SELECT 
    MinID = MIN(PerHour.MinId)
FROM 
(
    -- Local minimums (for each distinct hour value)
    SELECT 
        MinID = MIN(c.Id)
    FROM dbo.Connection AS c WITH(READUNCOMMITTED) 
    WHERE
        c.DateConnection = '2012-06-26' 
    GROUP BY
        c.[Hour]
) AS PerHour;
```

The execution plan is:

[image: Serial plan]

If parallelism is enabled, you will see a plan more like the following, which uses parallel index scan and multi-threaded stream aggregates to produce the result even faster:

[image: Parallel plan]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is quite usefull and well detailed. I will try that as soon as i have access to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Although it might be wise to fix the problem in a way that doesn't require index hints, a quick solution is this:

```
SELECT MIN(Id) FROM Connection WITH(NOLOCK, INDEX(PK_Connection)) WHERE DateConnection = '2012-06-26'
```

This forces a table scan.

Alternatively, try this although it probably produces the same problem:

```
select top 1 Id
from Connection
WHERE DateConnection = '2012-06-26'
order by Id
```

Answer (score -1):

It makes sense that finding the minimum takes longer than going through all the records. Finding the minimum of an unsorted structure takes much longer than traversing it once (unsorted because MIN() doesn't take advantage of the identity column). What you could do, since you're using an identity column, is have a nested select, where you take the first record from the set of records with the specified date.

Comment: I also tried to do this kind of select with no success. That's why I resort to using a temporary table.

`select min(id) from (select id from connection with(nolock) where dateconnection = '2012-06-26') t`

Comment: This doesn't make sense. While traversing the data (once) you can find the minimum. The reason is to be found elsewhere.

Answer (score -2):

The NC index scan is issue in you case.It is using the unique non clustered index scan and then for each row that is hundred million rows it will traverse the clustered index and thus it causes millions of io's(usually say your index hieght is 4 then it might cause 100million*4 IO's +index scan of the nonclustered index leaf page).Optimizer must have chosen this index to avoid the strem aggregate to get the minimum.To find minimum there are 3 main technique,one is using index on the column for which we want min (it is efficient if there is index and in that case no calc required as soon as you get the row it is returned),2nd it could use hash aggregate (but it usually happens when you have group by) and 3rd is stream aggregate here it will scan through all the rows which are qualified and keep the min value always and return min when all rows are scanned..

Howvere, when the query without min used the clustered index scan and thus is fast as it has to read less number of page and thus less io's.

Now question is why optimizer picked up the index scan on non clustered index.I am sure it is to avoid the compuation involved in stream aggregate to find the min value using stream aggregate but in thise case not using the stream aggregate is much more costly. This depends on estimation so i guess stats are not up to date in the table.

So fist of all check whether your stats are upto date.When was the stats were updated last?

Thus to avoid the issue.Do following 
1. First update the table stats and I am sure it must remove your issue.
2. In case, you can not use update stats or update stats doesnt change the plan and still uses the NC index scan then you can force the clustered index scan so that it uses less IO's followed by stream aggregate to get min value.

Comment: Finding the minimum never requires a sort operation.

Comment: There are number of methods to find minimum.like hash match,using index and stream aggregate.But in this case it is using the index and thus performance is severely bad.

Comment: True but calculating an aggregate without group-by never requires any sorting or hashing. Just a stream aggregate over an unsorted stream.

Comment: I will try this and i'll keep you up to date... Any case, thanks a lot for this detailed answer

Comment: No hashing is needed in this case it usually is required when you have group by thus a stream aggregate must have been done but even it is not used rather it used an index so the data is already sorted and whenever first row it will find with that date it will return the data .It behave more like top1 in this case and that caused too many IO's and thus bad performance.