# Can FORCE SCAN improve performance of query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I think FORCE SEEK can improve the performance of SELECT query, but wondering if FORCE SCAN can also improve performance of query.

Can someone explain with example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have a query that will result in 1.000.000 rows but SQL Server estimates there will only be 100.  Then SQL Server estimates 100 index seeks with a table lookup are faster than a full table scan.  But instead it ends up doing 1.000.000 index seeks and lookups!

In that case, adding a `force scan` hint will improve the performance of a query.

Note that this situation is unusual.  SQL Server tries to optimize for the worst case, and will not use a seek unless it's pretty damn sure there are not too many of them.  That's why `forceseek` is used more often `forcescan`.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't optimise for the worst case AFAIK it just chooses the plan with the lowest estimated cost. If it considered worst case scenarios you likely wouldn't end up with [issues like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481818/sql-why-is-select-count-mincol-maxcol-faster-then-select-mincol-max/7482342#7482342)

Comment: @MartinSmith: AFAIK, when based on the statistics, a query would result in 1-1.000 rows, the estimated cost is based on 1.000 rows.